# Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 14, in <module> usr_nmr=input() EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python

I'm getting an EOF error, but only in ZyBooks. PyCharm and VS Code both execute my code just fine. Any ideas?

```
usr_word1=input('enter a word')
usr_word2=input('enter another word')
usr_nmr=input('enter a number')

print('You entered '+usr_word1+' '+usr_word2+' '+usr_nmr)
first_pswd=usr_word1+'_'+usr_word2

second_pswd=usr_nmr+usr_word1+usr_nmr
print(first_pswd)
print(second_pswd)
```

Comment: You must not be entering three things.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I keep coming up with. In VS Code and PyCharm I'm entering inputs, however this is for a class that uses ZyBook. The interface is supposed to enter variables for you to test the code with different variable inputs.

Comment: Are you sure the interface feeds values in through stdin, and not as parameters to a function?